# Text Fields in android-studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Can someone tell me how to use a Text Field with an onclick listener on a button in android studio and give me the xaml code too.

Answer (score 1):

First you need write in xml file what you need, we need button and textview:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="textEdit"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:background="#333"
    android:onClick="ButtonOneClick"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtView"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:hint="text view"
/>
```

After xml you need define this in class. Because we define `android:onClick="ButtonOneClick"` in xml,
we can just call it , and set what you want to do.

```
TextView tv;

tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtView);

public void ButtonOneClick(View view) {
    tv.setText("Test");
}
```

Other method is to declare button to, and set `onClickListener`.

```
Button butt;
butt= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
butt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    tv.setText("Test")
  }
});
```

Comment: t tried the code you gave me and this is what i get when i start the app [link](http://puu.sh/hUzpn/0ab371ed83.png). this is the code i'm using [link](http://puu.sh/hUzty/3d852a578f.png) and this is the xaml code [link](http://puu.sh/hUzxE/4d4c8adb84.png) i don't know what is the problem.

Comment: You need to use logs to see what mistake is. But try to define  TextView tv; like global variable,and on create  tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtView); Find some examples on net for start

Answer (score 0):

in tampil.xml

```
 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:text="PENCET"
    android:onClick="onPencet" />
```

and in u're class, use **public void nameonClick(view v){ statement }**

```
public class Tampil {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

} 

public void onPencet(View v){
**U're statement }  
}
```